# Laravel 5 - query builder AND

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

i have a mysql query and i want to pass them to laravel but i don't know how to use AND in laravel.

Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `items_sizes` left join `items` on `items_sizes`.`id_item` = `items`.`id` left join `budget__items` on `items_sizes`.`id` = `budget__items`.`id_itemSize` and `budget__items`.`id_budget` = 1 where `items`.`active` = 1 and `budget__items`.`id_budget` is null order by `items_sizes`.`updated_at` asc
```

Laravel:

```
$itemsSizes = ItemsSize::leftJoin('items', 'items_sizes.id_item', '=','items.id')
        ->leftJoin('budget__items','items_sizes.id', '=', 'budget__items.id_itemSize')
        ->*AND*('budget__items.id_budget', '=', $id)
        ->where('items.active', '=', 1)
        ->whereNull('budget__items.id_budget')
        ->orderBy('items_sizes.updated_at', 'asc')
```

Thank's

Comment: Have you tried `->leftJoin('budget__items', 'budget__items.id_budget', '=', $id)` in place of `->*AND*('budget__items.id_budget', '=', $id)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
$itemsSizes = ItemsSize::leftJoin('items', 'items_sizes.id_item', '=','items.id')
    ->leftJoin('budget__items', function($join) use($id) {
        $join->on('items_sizes.id', '=', 'budget__items.id_itemSize')
        ->where('budget__items.id_budget', '=', $id);
    })
    ->where('items.active', '=', 1)
    ->whereNull('budget__items.id_budget')
    ->orderBy('items_sizes.updated_at', 'asc');
```

Comment: Thank's for answer me. this work if i put a int value in $id otherwise i have this error " Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'on clause' " ... the number 3 is the value of $id and not a column.

Comment: The `$id` wasn't available in the context of the anonymous  function I added the `use($id)`. Please revise your code !

Comment: How do you get the `$id` value ?